# Why cant I install android APK using gmail anymore?

Tags: android, download, gmail, apk

I have a tablet with WiFi but no USB cables.
I use to be able to install my signed APK using gmail, but it does not work anymore, when I open my email using the gmail I get the following prompt:

```
filename.apk
1.6MB APK File
INSTALL
```

When I press [INSTALL] the prompt changes to

```
filename.apk
Download failed APK file
INSTALL
```

It use to work just fine. Now I am stuck mucking with the SD card, so frustrating. What changed? I was unable to find an answer using google.

Answer (score 1):

Try to download it to local storage then install it

Also: if you have the apk already installed you can first try to uninstall it then install new one

Comment: What do you mean by download to local storage?